# @media print issue with SVG not displaying

Tags: css, svg

I want to make printable my website, I'm having issues with SVG in @media print, the problem is that SVG are not displaying when I print.

html5

```
<div class="svg-container">
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="{{ site.theme.link }}/asset/svg/{{ station.menu_order }}.svg" width="100%" height="100%" class="svg-content"></object>
</div>
```

css3

```
.svg-container {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 15%;
    padding-bottom: 4%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.svg-content {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.25em;
    left: 0;
}
```

Does anyone can help me ?

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from printing svg as is. So your @media rule is stopping you? The problem can both be in your css and svg can you post both or any one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer has been given by @SaraSoueidan
just need to define the width and the padding-bottom at 100%

```
.svg-container {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.svg-content {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```